# Calendar default display means

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

i have problem v default display in Calendar.

- First image: default display
- Second image:
- Next image: I need this display as default.

[image: My default display]

[image: Select means]

[image: This display i need default]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the default view to Show Weeks then follow

1. From ribbon select modify view
2. Set Default Scope = "Week"
3. Click Ok

Comment: Ok probably do not understand.
I now see a blank calendar, but I reserve funds there, you see only when I click environment - the room name (screen 2). I would need to have these funds selected by default.

In short, after clicking on the calendar, I would like to see the screen 3.

Answer (score 0):

Ok probably do not understand.
I now see a blank calendar, but I reserve funds there, you see only when I click environment - the room name (screen 2). I would need to have these funds selected by default.

In short, after clicking on the calendar, I would like to see the screen 3.